# C++ Program Crash on file output

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that takes a list of names and then outputs it to a `.txt` file.

This is my code:

```
void setNames() // Set method that takes a series of names.
{
  nameTags = new char*[numberOfNames];
  for (int i=0; i<=numberOfNames; i++)
  {
    nameTags[i] = new char[128];
    cout << "Input information for name " << i << ": " << "\n";
    cin.getline(namesSet, sizeof(namesSet));
    strcpy(nameTags[i], namesSet);
  }
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& ostr, const Names& names) // <<operator
{
  ostr << "#############################" << endl;
  ostr << names.getAuthor();
  ostr << names.getNumberOfNames();
  for(int i=0; i<=names.numberOfNames; i++)
  {
    ostr << names.nameTags [i] << "\n";
  }
  return ostr;
}
```

Now my program works fine and prints to a terminal. However, when I try running this after the `ofstream` it crashes and is not very good. For example, if I want to input 10 names, and save it to disk it crashes.

```
ofstream outputfile (names.getFileName());
if(outputfile.is_open())
{
  outputfile << names; // I believe I go wrong here.
  outputfile.close();
}
```

I am new to C++ and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out with my problem. I have been spending hours trying to fix it.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a dynamically allocated array of char*

Comment: If `getline` fails then your buffers will all be full of garbage which could cause the problem

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think it may be the `getline` that causes the bug.  I have declared `namesSet` as `char namesSet[100]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with statement:

```
for (int i=0; i<=numberOfNames; i++)
```

Instead it should be

```
for (int i=0; i < numberOfNames; i++)
```

Also in the stream insertion operator it should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < names.numberOfNames; i++)
```

Comment: +1. Writing past the end of the buffer could definitely account for it.

Comment: I just tried that... doesn't make a difference. Like I mentioned, I think its the output file stream

Comment: @user4167396: This is a bug nonetheless, leading to undefined behavior. You may have other bugs as well.

Comment: @user4167396: If fixing this bug didn't solve the problem, I think you have errors in code you haven't shown. For example, I'm suspicious of `sizeof(namesSet)`, since `sizeof` on a pointer is a common bug. But you haven't shown the declaration of `namesSet`.

Comment: @FredLarson `namesSet` is declared as `char namesSet[100]`